# VMware Restart -- Blank Screen

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-server

I am running VMWare Server on a Windows 2K8 server. I was wondering what the default behavior is for a restart or shutdown initiated from within the virtual host? Currently, when I restart the virtual host and view this from the console viewer, the host shuts down and the console turns blue. This also happens for a restart initiated from within the virtual host.

Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 1):

The usual behaviour, as I have experienced it, is:

- When you select 'Power Off', the VM console should go black.
- When you select 'Shut down guest', if VMware Tools are installed, the OS should go through its normal shutdown process and then the VM console should go black.
- When you select 'Reset', the VM console should go black and then start the BIOS load.
- When you select 'Restart guest', if VMware Tools are installed, the VM console should go through normal shutdown, then the console should go black and then start the BIOS load.

Of course, I have only done this from a Windows 2003 server, so blue might be the new black!

Does the console kick back in when the server is restarted?

Comment: I am experiencing strange behavior with this VMWare installation. When I restart the host from within the host (Start > Restart...not using VMWare menu), the virtual host powers down and the console goes blue. The VM does not automatically restart. I have the manually click the RESET button. Is there a setting that might be preventing the VM from restarting?

Comment: I think you are mistaking 'host' for 'guest'.  The host is the Windows 2008 that you installed VMware Server on.  The guest is a VM run by VMware Server.  If you are restarting the host, you are restarting the physical computer.  If you are restarting the guest, you should see the console go through the steps mentioned above

Comment: Hmm...that is not what I am seeing. I wonder why? The guest machine's screen turns to blue in the console and does not restart.